# Dual monitors Dell P2415Q 13" MacBook Pro 2018, 2.7 GHZ Quad Core i7, 16gb RAM, 256gb SSD

Tags: macbook-pro, display, performance

I'm looking to buy dual Dell 4k 24-inch [P2415Q](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-24-ultra-hd-4k-monitor-p2415q/apd/210-agnk/monitors-monitor-accessories) monitors for my new 13" Macbook Pro 2018. I'm concerned about iGPU performance.

Has anyone already tried to run dual 4k monitors on 13" Macbook pro 2018 with 2.7ghz quad core i7 and 16gb RAM? Apple says it's possible, but what about your real experience and performance when you do additional WEB development and light graphic works.

If it's not possible to keep fans cold and quiet, daily UX lag-free, probably I will stay with a single 24" or 27" monitor.

**Front-End Development**: Chrome, Firefox & Safari (with many loaded tabs), Sublime Text (IDE), CyberDuck (FTP), Sequel Pro (DBS), SourceTree (Git)

**Graphic**: Pixelmator (light photos/logos editing), Sketch (simple drawings), Figma, Axure RP, Google Web Designer

**Other**: MS Office, Dropbox, OneDrive, Google Drive, Harvester, Viber, WhatsApp, Spotify, Slack, Skype, Telegram

BTW, I'm not interested in 15" Macbook Pro. Waiting for any opinion. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  I am tending toward this question being "unclear" because of this vague statement:  *additional WEB development and light graphic works.*  What is that?  Can you give ***specifics*** as to what this means?  Remember, *web development* and *light graphics work* are very different things for different people so be very specific when describing them.

Comment: I will give you a list of apps which are running mostly all the time so you can better understand my multitasking: 

**Front-End Development**: Chrome, Firefox & Safari (with many loaded tabs), Sublime Text (IDE), CyberDuck (FTP), Sequel Pro (DBS), SourceTree (Git)
| **Graphic**: Pixelmator, Sketch, Figma, Axure RP, Google Web Designer
| **Other**: MS Office, Dropbox, OneDrive, Google Drive, Harvester, Viber, WhatsApp, Spotify, Slack, Skype, Telegram

Comment: Please *edit* your original question with these details.  Also, it's not what apps you use, it's how you use them (Sketch...complex/simple drawings?)  Is it maxing out now with what you're running?

Comment: @Allan yes, it's all what I'm using right now. BTW, Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using dual 4K Displays with my MacBook Pro 2017. The Performance is okay, no lags or problems with the fans.

It's the best Workstation I've ever had, so I hope you'll have fun with it.

Edit: I'm using two LG UltraFine 4K Display

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Do you use 13" or 15" Macbook Pro? And what type of work do you do or apps using so I can better imagine the performance 

Comment: As an app developer I use xCode.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I assume you use 13" Macbook Pro, correct?

Comment: Yes it's easier for me to have a small notebook for traveling.

Comment: could you please mark my answer as solved?